# Best way to implement an "reorderable" Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of entities shown to the user more or less as a list. Now the user may not only add or delete entities but also reorder the existing ones (with the typical "go up", "go down", "go to the top", "go to the bottom" operations).

But what is the best way to implement this behavior? Of course I can code all the needed operations "manually" in the service layer, but this functionality seems to be a common requirement, so maybe there is already some kind of standard solution?

Comment: reorderable where ? in another entity? since you're tagging this as JPA then I assume in another entity.

Comment: No. The entities of this type must be just sortable. The problem is that the sort order may be changed by the user at any time ("now this entity needs to go up in the list"). This is what I mean by "reorderable".

Comment: So if you don't mean "on retrieval from the DB" then just set the ORDER BY clause on your JPQL query. If you mean after the data is retrieved then put them in a SortedSet and define a comparator ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most suitable bidirectional collection, is an [ordered List](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-favoring-sets-vs-bags/):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderColumn("order_id")
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

The `order_id` column will be used to sort elements upon retrieval and when you change the element order, Hibernate will issue the appropriate updates to set the `order_id` column based on the current element index.

Comment: Don't you mean @OrderColumn? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433195/hibernate-orderby-vs-ordercolumn-to-maintain-the-order-of-a-collection

Comment: Exactly. In that article the OrderBy was simply emulating a Bag semantics. OrderColumn is what I had in mind. Thanks.