# How Hibernate sorts collection with @OrderColumn annotation?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

As I can see from generated SQL while querying entities with collection mapped like this:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Long.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "LIST_GAMES", 
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LIST_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
@Column(name = "GAME_ID")
@OrderColumn(name = "GAME_ORDER")
private List<Long> gameIds;
```

Hibernate doesn't add any 'order by' statements to it. So does it mean, that collection is sorted in-memory after loading? Or does it means that I need a complex index on db level like (LIST_ID, GAME_ORDER) to handle order by in the db?

**UP:** My question is actually **HOW** hibernate sorts this collection? Is It handled by hibernate in-memory or its retrieved already sorted from db? And am I need to create database index for GAME_ORDER column?

Answer (score 1):

OrderBy adds an order by clause to the generated SQL to order the members of the retrieved collection by a column of the table of the target entity:

```
@OrderBy("GAME_ORDER ASC")
public List<Long> gameIds;
will generate a SQL query like
```

select ... order by game.game_order ASC

`@OrderColumn` defines the name of an additional column in the table, containing the index of the entity in the list. 
If you change the ordering of the elements in the list, Hibernate will change the value of this column. And if your gameId have 0, 3, and 5 as values in this column, the list will be

```
[gameIds0, null, null, gameIds3, null, gameIds5]
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433410/4985572)

Answer (score 1):

Answering the OP's updated question since no one answered it and I didn't find a lot in my Google searches that explained how `@OrderColumn` actually works.

If you're using `@OrderColumn`, indeed you will not see an `ORDER BY` clause in the generated query. Instead what happens is Hibernate will query all of the rows *completely deferring to what the database query plan decides the order will be when there is no `ORDER BY`* and do [this code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentList.java#L398) (from Hibernate 5.6. Other versions probably vary)

1. Get the row data from the persister (populates the persistence object)
2. Get the value (current index) for the column specified for `@OrderColumn` from the persister
3. Add null entries in the list up till the max order index it's seen
4. Puts the populated persistence object in the list at the current index

I want to draw attention again to the fact that because there is no `ORDER BY` clause, **Hibernate will just use the rows in the order the database gives it back.** So if for some reason you have multiple rows with the same order index value, Hibernate will drop all of them except for the last one with that order index value.

And [don't be tempted to think](https://web.archive.org/web/20160808070425/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/) that you'll always get the rows back in primary key order.

Answer (score -2):

As per [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) @OrderColumn is:

> Specifies a column that is used to maintain the persistent order of a
>   list. The persistence provider is responsible for maintaining the
>   order upon retrieval and in the database. The persistence provider is
>   responsible for updating the ordering upon flushing to the database to
>   reflect any insertion, deletion, or reordering affecting the list.

So it is likely that the collection is sorted after the data  is retrieved from the database and it is done in memory.

Comment: @NeilStockton If the persistence provider does not have permission to add `SURROGATE COLUMN`, could you please explain how does sorting take place?

Comment: Hi @NeilStockton, could you please refer any official JPA document where it is written that @OrderColumn is dependent on `SURROGATE COLUM`? I mean either `Sun` or `Oracle` doc.

Comment: @NeilStockton The apache doc says `The INDEX function returns an integer value corresponding to the position of its argument in an ordered list. The INDEX function can only be applied to identification variables denoting types for which an order column has been specified.` Is this `INDEX` related with database `INDEX`?

Comment: I have searched the whole `JPA 2.1 Specification` but no where did I find the  mention of `SURROGATE COLUMN`.

Comment: Sorry to say that I have used @OrderColumn with Hibernate as persistence provider but did not find any such column created any where in the database. Anybody can see that. Why are you saying `like the JPA spec says`? Where it (JPA spec) is saying such thing with respect to @OrderColumn? If you are so sure why you are not providing links to prove your point (only `oracle` or `sun` links) ?